Can I create an XPATH expression in Notepad++ with results I can paste into a spreadsheet?
Here is my source xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <Dog ID="Rover" Breed="Sheep Dog">
        <feature name="Trick1">
            <value>
                <trick>Roll Over</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Trick2">
            <value>
                <trick>SheepToBarn</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
    </Dog>
   <Dog ID="Spike" Breed="Chihuahua">
        <feature name="Trick1">
            <value>
                <trick>Scream</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Trick2">
            <value>
                <trick>Attack</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Trick3">
            <value>
                <trick>PoopInPurse</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
    </Dog>
    <Dog ID="Larry" Breed="Hound">
        <feature name="Hunt1">
            <value>
                <technique>FlushOutRabbits</technique>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Hunt2">
            <value>
                <technique>TreeRaccoons</technique>
            </value>
        </feature>
    </Dog>
    <Cat ID="Connie" Breed="Calico">
        <feature name="Trick1">
            <value>
                <trick>Chase Laser</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Trick2">
            <value>
                <trick>Sit In Box</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
    </Cat>
    <Bird ID="Polly" Breed="AfricanGray">
        <feature name="Trick1">
            <value>
                <trick>Whistle</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
        <feature name="Trick2">
            <value>
                <trick>Sing</trick>
            </value>
        </feature>
    </Bird>
</file>

I have created this xml as a proxy for my actual data.
At the <Dog>, <Cat>, <Bird> level shown above, the actual
text is either "Module" or "Module_Instance"
Here is my XPath Expression
//feature[contains(@name,'Trick')]/ancestor-or-self::/@ID |//feature[contains(@name,'Trick')]/ancestor-or-self::/@Breed |//feature[contains(@name,'Trick')]/ancestor-or-self::*/@name | //feature[contains(@name,'Trick')]/value/trick
Here is the Notepad++ result

I would like the information in the clip board to drop into a worksheet like this.

I tried Xpath as shown.  I have 2 problems:
1- getting the Notepad++ result in tabular form and
2- getting the element name "feature" from the xml so it can be used in cell C1.
I have not yet figured out Xquery in Notepad++ but I'm getting some traction with Xquery in BaseX

Did the answer not help? I think it will be difficult to control the output with pure XPath 1.0 only that probably the Notepad++ XML tools plugin supports. But outside of Notepad BaseX seems a good and powerful alternative and even has the easily accessible online fiddle in the browser now.

Using XQuery (e.g. with BaseX online at this fiddle) you could use
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

//trick!string-join((ancestor::Dog!(@ID, @Breed),ancestor::feature!@name, .), ', ')

and get e.g.
Rover, Sheep Dog, Trick1, Roll Over
Rover, Sheep Dog, Trick2, SheepToBarn
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick1, Scream
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick2, Attack
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick3, PoopInPurse

Your comments and edit suggest your XML is more complicated, it looks like using //trick!string-join((ancestor::*[@ID]!(@ID, @Breed),ancestor::feature!@name, .), ', ') instead of //trick!string-join((ancestor::Dog!(@ID, @Breed),ancestor::feature!@name, .), ', ') might help to address that.

Please excuse me for not having "sanitized" my original XML correctly.  My original queries were based on a node with a @name attribute starting with "Trick".  But the ancestor nodes might not all be "Dog".  I'm sorry and a bit ashamed that I don't know how to replace my XML in this post,  If I add cat named connie with breed calico with trick 1 of "chase laser" and trick 2 of "sit in box" and add a bird named Polly with of breed AfricanGrey with trick 1 of "whistle" and trick 2 of "sing".  The original solution provided does not work because not all ancestors are dogs.

@DBacker, you can edit your question at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78532889/edit. Also explain whether you know the names of the elements like Cat and Dog when writing the query or whether there is some other way to identify and select those elements, perhaps ancestor::*[@ID], i.e. the ancestor element that has an ID attribute.

Martin - 1000 thanks for your help!  I have updated the entry to include at the ,   level is expected to be either  or <Module_Instance>

@DBacker, see whether the edit helps you to adjust your code to get what you want, I am afraid saying the entries can be Dog, Cat or Bird to then state something about Module or Module_Instance doesn't make it clearer. I have gone with the generic ancestor::*[@ID] as a hopefully helpful way to select the elements. If not, better ask a new question with a clear and precise description of the XML and the wanted result.

Martin - you did it!  1000 thanks.  I just replaced Dog! with  !                                                                                                                           //trick!string-join((ancestor::!(@ID, @Breed),ancestor::feature!@name, .), ', ')Rover, Sheep Dog, Trick1, Roll Over
Rover, Sheep Dog, Trick2, SheepToBarn
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick1, Scream
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick2, Attack
Spike, Chihuahua, Trick3, PoopInPurse
Connie, Calico, Trick1, Chase Laser
Connie, Calico, Trick2, Sit In Box
Polly, AfricanGray, Trick1, Whistle
Polly, AfricanGray, Trick2, Sing
